# My armstrong number program has a logical error

Tags: python-3.x

This code always displays only the `else` statement in output, even if user has entered an armstrong number. Is there something wrong with my `if-else` statement?
I have tried indenting it properly, checking the syntax.

```
num=int(input("enter number :   "))
num1=num
sum=0
while(num!=0):
    sum+=(num%10)**3
    num/=10

if(sum==num1):
    print(sum," is an armstrong number ")
else:
    print("go find another number")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using floating point division. You should use floor division `//`. Then compute the exponent from the length of the number so this works for Armstrong numbers of varying length (not just 3):

```
num = int(input("enter number :   "))
num1 = num
sum = 0
exp = len(str(num))
while(num != 0):
   sum += (num % 10) ** exp
   num //= 10 # here

if(sum == num1):
   print(sum," is an armstrong number ")
else:
   print("go find another number")
```

Comment: my code asks for input from the user. this program doesn't. my error is in if else statement. i just want to know how to edit accordingly. please answer accordingly.

Comment: The error isn't in the `if-else` but in the `while` loop. I've updated the code

Comment: thank you for your help. the error message isn't there now and the program works fine.
could you please explain how floor function works and floating point division doesn't.

Comment: Take `371` as your test number, with floating point division, in the first iteration `num /= 10` will return `37.1` which give `sum` a floating point value in the next iteration. Same happens in the following iterations: `3.71`. But with floor division `num` goes from `371` to `37` then to `3`, which is the right progression that can help you get a non `float` modulo for `sum`

Comment: nice explaination. i am a beginner so am having trouble .